# Error writing trigger statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to limit the size of a table to X rows (I'll use 5 for example). When the limit is reached, I want to copy the oldest row to another table, then delete it. I currently have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LimitRows BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) >= 5 THEN

    INSERT INTO HistoryTable
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable A
    WHERE vhID = A.min(vhID);

    DELETE FROM MyTable
    WHERE vhID = min(vhID); 

    END IF;    
END;
```

Currently, I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

How do I write this trigger correctly? Also, how can I modify to cut the table down to 5 rows if it starts out at something like 100 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter first

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER LimitRows BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) >= 5 THEN

    INSERT INTO HistoryTable
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable A
    WHERE vhID = A.min(vhID);

    DELETE FROM MyTable
    WHERE vhID = min(vhID); 

    END IF;    
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the trigger definition would end at the first `;` which would make it incomplete.

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having, but unfortunately my statement was invalid. Can't modify the same table you are INSERTing into. Still, since this fixes that particular error I'll mark it as the answer.